# why in double precision (IEEE standard) 49 is the first positive integer that k * (1 / k) is not exactly 1?

Tags: ieee-754

why in double precision (IEEE standard) 49 is the first positive integer that k * (1 / k) is not exactly 1.?

Comment: i doubt there is much interesting in this. When `1/k` is calculated in floating-point, there is a rounding error. When something is multiplied by `k` there is a rounding error. Apparently 49 is the first time those to rounding errors amount to enough to change the result from 1. It is probably not anything profound about the value 49. Perhaps there is some number-theoretic aspect or some magnitude limitation that was crossed, but I am skeptical.

Comment: I searched for the first failures of `k*(1/k) == 1` for significand widths from 1 to 26. They are 1: 11, 2: 13, 3: 29, 4: 19, 5: 25, 6: 13, 7: 55, 8: 61, 9: 27, 10: 25, 11: 11, 12: 23, 13: 45, 14: 13, 15: 43, 16: 45, 17: 97, 18: 13, 19: 29, 20: 27, 21: 11, 22: 19, 23: 23, 24: 41, 25: 25, 26: 13. I do not see a particular pattern.